# AngularJs Adding ... and close all tags to an excerpt

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I want to build an excerpt filter for my app.

From my backend I get an string like this:

```
<p>this is gonna be a very long text</p>
```

With LimitTo from Angluarjs I get:

```
<p>this is gonna be a ver
```

But I want this:

```
<p>this is gonna be a ver...</p>
```

The reason why I want to close these tags is that I could get any possible tags from my backend.

How could I check if all elements are closed and add ... to the last element?

**Edit:**

Here a better Example:

I get a JSON from my backend like:

```
{ text: "<p>This is a very long text with a <a href=\"#\">very long link</a> and some more attributes. Propably a <img src=\"image.png\"> too.</p>"}
```

I insert this data to my view like this:

```
<div ng-bind-html="json.text"></div>
```

The result should look like this:

```
<div>
  <p>This is a very long text with a <a href=\"#\">very long</a>...</p>
  <button>read more</button>
</div>
```

If there is an image in my string and my "cut" is in this tag I want to remove the image. So I get

```
<div>
  <p>This is a very long text with a <a href=\"#\">very long link</a> and some more attributes. Propably a ...</p>
  <button>read more</button>
</div>
```

instead of

```
<div>
  <p>This is a very long text with a <a href=\"#\">very long link</a> and some more attributes. Propably a <img sr...</p>
  <button>read more</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You could use [ellipsis](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp)

Comment: It's a bit more complicated. This is just the easiest case. But it would be too complicated to describe everything. For example: In case of too long text I have to add a button too

Comment: So you want to apply a directive to your `<p>` tag? Couldn't you use a filter ? Sounds more appropriate.

Comment: You are right - a filter would be a better idea. But it is still the same problem

Comment: What is your breaking point ? A number of character or a width of the element ?

Comment: why are you getting HTML from your backend? are you trying to display user generated HTML content?  this seems like a case where `$sce` would be appropriate.

Comment: What are you getting from the backend? Only the text within the `<p> </p>` tags or including the tags? Normally you could use the following CSS modifiers: `overflow: hidden` and `text-overflow: ellipsis`.

Comment: FE: I could get something like `<p>my Text includes a <a href="#">very very very long link text</a></p>`. If this is too long, i want to add [..] and a "show more"-button. text-overflow does not work because i want it multi line. I know there are CSS properties for but this is not the result I want

Comment: I've added a better example. The lenght of my string is defined by the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a lot of tests with RegExp I decided to use another technique.

In case someone else got a simular question I wanted to post my solution.

```
.text__wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}    

.text-preview {
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  max-height: 140px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: normal;
}

.text-preview:after {
  top: 115px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); 
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#FFFFFF',GradientType=0 ); 
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  content: " ";
}
```

This is not the solution i wanted but this works for me. Here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/2s09e2dv/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to truncate the text, you can use css like:

```
p {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}
```

see this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xie_qianyue/rwep0zax/).

EDIT:
By modifying the displaying text, you can emulate the hide/show effect, see this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xie_qianyue/u38ywasq/).

Comment: Thanks but this is not what i need. I've added a better example to specify my problem

Comment: I know this technique. But the main Problem is that the user should be able to insert images too. I've edited your fiddle to show you what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/u38ywasq/1/ as you see the image tag is cut off. I dont use {{text}}. I use ng-bind-html="text". THanks for your help but i found another solution